# Find pressure on screen when touch in corona?

Tags: coronasdk

In my corona application,i have to find pressure on the screen when i touch.please help me.its possible in iphone but in corona its possible or not.

Comment: You want to know how much pressure a person is making on the screen when it is touched?

Comment: can u give me some idea .how to measure the weight in iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corona does not support pressure settings.